# Keep filters from Power BI Services in Excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

Hello guys,

I'm connecting Excel to reports (or dataset) of Power BI Services. I can retrieve the data but I still have to "recreate" all the filters I had in Power BI Services (visual filter, report filter or page filter).

Is there a way to keep those filters applied in the report in Excel? that way the business will be able to have the exact same view of PBI when they Analyze in Excel.

Thanks a lot.